# Matlab immse formula is different from expected

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mse

I am trying to calculate the MSE between two images.

1. In Matlab the `immse` function contains an unexpected formula which is `(norm(x(:)-y(:),2).^2)/numel(x)`.
2. My teacher instead is using `mean((x(:)-y(:)).^2)`.

I saw that the results of the method with the mean is more or less half of the other's method.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), my teacher's version seems to be the correct one.

What's the right version to use? Why are there these differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different forms of computing the same thing, and they do give the same answer. We can test this is the same using an example

```
rng(0);
x = rand(3,3); 
y = rand(3,3);
immse( x, y );       % = 0.20527
mean((x(:)-y(:)).^2) % = 0.20527
```

This is why...

According to the [norm documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bvhji30-1), `norm(v,2)` is equivalent to `norm(v)` or the Euclidean norm, defined as the square root of the sum of squares

[image: Euclidean norm]

Your own Wikipedia link defines MSE as

[image: MSE]

We can combine these (using consistent lettering for `n`=`N` an `k`=`i` from the two sources)

Definition of `norm(v,2)` and this expression squared:

[image: norm]

Let:

[image: v definition]

And substitute into the MSE equation:

[image: MSE]

Which is the calculation done within `immse`: `(norm(x(:)-y(:),2).^2)/numel(x)`

So the definitions given by Wikipedia and MATLAB's `immse` are the same. The introductory sentence for the Wiki article even mentions the norm

> As it is derived from the square of Euclidean distance [...]

This is equivalent to your teacher's definition. They are using `mean` to perform the summation over `i=1..n` and division by `n`, and computing the square of the delta which is the same as the squared Euclidean norm.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think that my problem is linked to the fact that x and y were `uint8`; if i cast them to `double`, then the value in the mean's version equals the one outputted from `imsse`.